# oracle sequence thread safety can it return CURVAL of its thread when other thread attempts NEXTVAL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know that oracle sequence is supposed to be thread safe when incrementing. However, what about when just retrieving current value?

Say for example below

```
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        IF i = 1 THEN
            INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES (test_seq3.NEXTVAL,'BB');
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES (test_seq3.CURRVAL,'BB');
        END IF;                
    END LOOP;
END;
```

if I run above statement in two different threads, is it possible for test_seq3 to be incremented twice before the first loop finishes?

Comment: CURRVAL is just the last value returned by the sequence *for that session*. Thread safety doesn't come into it.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp so the session is each insert right?

Comment: No, the whole PL/SQL block is executed in a single session.

Comment: So this code will insert the same value for all 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the CURRVAL will be consistent for a given session.

Why don’t you try it and see; you pretty much have s test case written.

Comment: session refers to each insert in this case?

Comment: It refers to the entire BEGIN; END; block